# Program to report length based on coordinates in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I'm trying to write a program that allows the user to enter a trip as a sequence of any number of map references on one line, and reports the total length of the trip, assuming they can travel in straight lines.

The desired output is

```
Enter Trip Map References: E6 E4 D7 d43 F5
Bad reference: d43
```

0r

```
Enter Trip Map References: C2 B5 Y25
    Total distance = 16.8km
```

so far my current code is :

```
dict = {}
n = input("Enter trip map references: ") . split()
print (n)

for i in n:
    if i.isupper()==False:
        print("Bad reference: ",i)
    else:
        i = i.lower()
        for character.isalpha() == True:
            number = ord(character) -96
            character = character.upper()
            dict[character] = number
print(dict)
 for i in n:
     x = i[0]
     y = i[1]
     if x in dict:
         i = (dict[x],int(y))
```

My problem is I'm stuck having to select each coordinate and execute Pythagora's formula (sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2) for the 2 of the coordinates. The Pythagora's formula should execute starting between the first 2 coordinates, then 2nd and 3rd and then 3rd and 4th, and so on.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you include a copy of the code for the map object and its values.  Also `dict` in python is a data type, you shouldn't use it as a variable name.  Also  what is `character` referring to in your code.

Comment: @alexpdev the map object and values are as follows x -cord  ( a-z) y - cord ( 1 -26) Character is referring to Letters in my case probably not an efficient way, sorry.

Comment: edit your answer to include that information... so others can see it as well

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the formula like this:

```
from math import sqrt

point1 = (0,0)
point2 = (1,1)

result = (sqrt(point2[0] - point1[0]))**2 + (sqrt(point2[1]-point1[1]))**2
```

So a kind of abstract example would be.

```
points = [p1,p2,p3,p4]

for i in range(1,len(points)):
    j = i - 1
    p1 = points[i]
    p2 = points[j]
    result = (sqrt(p2[0] - p1[0]))**2 + (sqrt(p2[1]-p1[1]))**2
```

You could also try the `hypot` function in the math module as suggested by  Ture Pålsson

Comment: Using [math.hypot](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot) might save a bit of typing and reduce the risk for numeric errors.

Comment: @TurePålsson  Good call  i didn't even know that was a thing

Comment: @alexpdev would you be able to rectify my code to include both my original and your suggested answer> I know I have a syntax error in my code aswell